# Make a class from one project visible in other project (Python,Pycharm)

Tags: python, class, pycharm

I created in PyCharm a Class in Project1, called Class1. Now I have created Project2 (no matter in which directory). I want Class1 to be imported in this project (Project2) as well (like all other modules, like os, requests, numpy). Could you please advice how I can do it?

I have tried:
- from Class1.py import Class1
- marked as source code directory of Project1

Still when writing in window of Project2 "from Class1.py import Class1" interpreter does not recognize it

Answer (score 1):

Finding code to import python interpreter looks at `sys.path`.

https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html

So that you should add some lines of code

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path to project1')
```

Or use PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to modify PYTHONPATH (import path). Import path is a list that will be checked by the third default finder during importation process.
The first finder will locate built-in modules and the second frozen modules.

Read this for more information : https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/import.html

If your class1.py is in "/home/project1"
you can do in terminal :

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/project1`

or directly in python terminal :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/project1")
```